# Constructor Event in class Event<T> cannot be applied to given types; cannot find symbol method getTitle()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect my app with the Firebase database but it gives me a Fatal exception error: ( i did not post the rest of the code that I implemented before because it was working perfectly well. Just after the implementation of the code bellow I got an error )

```
package com.example.guideme;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.Autocomplete;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.model.AutocompleteActivityMode;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.example.guideme.Event;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText locationEditText, titleEditText,descriptionEditText;
    Button publish, inviteFriends;
    TextView tvDate;
    ListView listView;
    private static final String TAG ="MainActivity";
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

    public String title, description, date, location;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //hooks to all elements in activity_main.xml
        locationEditText = findViewById(R.id.locationEditText);
        titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        descriptionEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
        publish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.publish);
        tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        inviteFriends = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inviteFriends);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);




        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                getAllTasks(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                //Failed to read value
               Log.w("events", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

                publish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                title = titleEditText.getText().toString();
                date = tvDate.getText().toString();
                description = descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
                location = locationEditText.getText().toString();

                String id = title.replaceAll("\\s","");

                writeNewUser(id, title, date, location, description);

                titleEditText.setText("");
                descriptionEditText.setText("");
                tvDate.setText("");
                locationEditText.setText("");

            }
        });


    private void writeNewUser (String eventId, String title, String location, String date, String description){
            Event event = new Event (title, location, date, description);
            mDatabase.child(eventId).setValue(event);
        }

        private void getAllTasks (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayList<String> aEvents = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Event event = singleSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                aEvents.add(event.getTitle());
            }

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aEvents);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if ( requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            locationEditText.setText(place.getAddress());

        }else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR){
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),status.getStatusMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //set the Gmail SDK
    public void open (View view) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent ();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                .append("<body><p>Content</p></body>")
                .toString()));
        sendIntent.setType("text/html");
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    }
}
```

I should have a null object reference (non-existant) that I am trying to convert to string, but I can not see this problem. Thank you.

error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: It's not the same `Event` class you show. You imported `Event` from Firebase, not the class you attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the following error:

> cannot find symbol method getTitle()

Because in this class `com.google.firebase.events.Event`, there is no `getTitle()` method. However, in your project, there is an Event class that should be imported. To solve this, simply change the following lines of code:

```
import com.google.firebase.events.Event;
```

To:

```
import com.example.guideme.Event;
```

Comment: It does not show me the error anymore on Mainjava.java, but instead, it gives me a fatal exception.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to say what may be wrong. In this case, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the MainActivity.java. I changed the code above.  Thank you for your help.